# Using multiple DELETEs in MySQL instead of a JOIN DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete, delete-row

In MySQL, I want to delete rows in table t1 and all the related rows in table t2 where some condition is met (say some status of some kind).

I know I can do this:

```
DELETE t1 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
WHERE t1.some_id = t2.some_id
AND t1.status=3;
```

But there is some dangling data in t2 that is not referenced by t1 and I want to delete that too (it's and old battered DB). I think I could do an outer join for this and UNION it with the inner join. But it gets more complicated because I need to delete rows in about 10 tables, all related by IDs. The end result was a crazy big query.

So I resulted in doing this:

```
DELETE FROM t1
WHERE status=3;

DELETE FROM t2 
WHERE some_id NOT IN (SELECT some_ID FROM t1)

DELETE FROM t3 
WHERE some_id NOT IN (SELECT some_ID FROM t2)
```

and so on for all the tables. That way all the un-referenced data is removed and it is more readable. Please note that there are no foreign keys and I cannot alter tables (so forget about "cascade delete").

So, is that wrong? 
What are the downsides of doing it the way I did it?

Thanks

Edit: 
The tables are big, t1 has half million rows, t2 has 3 millions rows, the 8 other tables less than half million. But I'm also deleting a lot of data, about 75%.

Edit 2: 
Ok I'll show you the real thing instead of just an example.
The purpose of this is to delete about 250000 old tickets in osTicket (after they were backed up).

Working in a VM, I first tried this:

```
DELETE ticket, thread, event, cdata, user, email, email_info
FROM       ost_ticket            AS ticket 
INNER JOIN ost_ticket_thread     AS thread 
INNER JOIN ost_ticket_event      AS event
INNER JOIN ost_ticket__cdata     AS cdata
INNER JOIN ost_user              AS user
INNER JOIN ost_user_email        AS email
INNER JOIN ost_ticket_email_info AS email_info
WHERE ticket.ticket_id = thread.ticket_id
AND   ticket.ticket_id = event.ticket_id
AND   ticket.ticket_id = cdata.ticket_id
AND   ticket.user_id   = user.id
AND   ticket.user_id   = email.user_id
AND   thread.id        = email_info.thread_id
AND   ticket.status_id=3 
AND   (ticket.closed < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY));
```

That only purges 7 tables, I need to add at least 2-3 tables to it. Maybe more. It takes 15 minutes to run and leaves a lot of un-referenced data in there.

Then I went with this (in a refreshed VM)

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM ost_ticket WHERE status_id=3 AND (closed < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY));
DELETE FROM ost_ticket_thread WHERE ticket_id NOT IN (SELECT ticket_id FROM ost_ticket);
DELETE FROM ost_ticket_event WHERE ticket_id NOT IN (SELECT ticket_id FROM ost_ticket);
DELETE FROM ost_ticket__cdata WHERE ticket_id NOT IN (SELECT ticket_id FROM ost_ticket);
DELETE FROM ost_user WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM ost_ticket);
DELETE FROM ost_user_email WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM ost_user);
DELETE FROM ost_ticket_email_info WHERE thread_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM ost_ticket_thread);
COMMIT;
```

It takes all the data out and takes 8 minutes to run.

Comment: The only downside that comes to mind is that you are not doing this as an atomic transaction if that even matters. Given the age/state of the database sounds like transaction integrity is not make or break. Perhaps others with have ideas.

Comment: I don't see a problem with doing it that way.

Comment: There are multi-table deletes. [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, mba12. I did not think about atomicity. Maybe I could wrap all those deletes in a transaction?

Comment: Uueerdo, aren't multi-table deletes just deletes with joins?

Comment: Nope, at least not when you specify a table before the FROM like you did in the first query, see answer I posted below if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

It is not wrong to do it in 3 separate `DELETE` queries.
Pros:

- more readable
- it doesn`t do heavy joins (if the tables are big) - in some cases it may execute faster

Cons:

- if tables are big then second and third query may be slow, because the subquery  select will return a lot of data ....
- you would get delete in 3 steps instead of one - which means you would have data in t2 and t3 after the first delete query, and in t3 after second delete .... which depending on the application may be good or not

I would advise you for more optimal way:

```
DELETE FROM t3 
WHERE some_id IN (SELECT some_ID FROM t2 
WHERE some_id IN (SELECT some_ID FROM t1 WHERE status=3))

DELETE FROM t2 
WHERE some_id IN (SELECT some_ID FROM t1 WHERE status=3)

DELETE FROM t1
WHERE status=3;
```

If you deleting **less** rows in **t1** than the rows **left** in **t1** (after the deletion)  this order will be faster. Don`t forget to delete from t1 in the last query because the above deletes depend on t1 :). But this order is valid only if it is some what of cascade delete (t1 rows that should be deleted are related to t2 and t3)

Comment: I'm not positive, but I don't think you want that `NOT IN` on the `t3` delete when executing the queries in that order; do you?

Comment: That's not too bad with 3 tables but with about 10 tables, it gets heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Anything particularly wrong with using multi-table delete syntax like this?

```
DELETE t1, t2, t3 
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.some_ID = t2.some_ID
INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.some_ID = t3.some_ID
WHERE t1.status=3
;
```

I know if you have foreign keys this can sometimes cause issues with MySQL deleting referenced rows before referencing rows; but you've stated you don't have those.